`dotnet test`-- how can I suppress irrelevant console outputs
Here's a sample of the console outputs that I have
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Net80WindowsTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

Starting test execution, please wait...
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: 5 ms - TestLibNet80.dll (net8.0)
  Failed ZZZRunSTA [10 s]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 1
  But was:  2

  Stack Trace:
     at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.AAASerializationTest.ZZZRunSTA() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\AAASerializationTest.cs:line 48

1)    at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.AAASerializationTest.ZZZRunSTA() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\AAASerializationTest.cs:line 48



Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     4, Skipped:     0, Total:     5, Duration: 16 s - Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Net80WindowsTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

Starting test execution, please wait...
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test matches the given testcase filter `TestCategory!=MemoryTest&TestCategory!=ApartmentSTA&FullyQualifiedName~Net80WindowsTest.AAA` in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll

  Failed GlobalTimeOutFail [5 s]
  Error Message:
   Test exceeded Timeout value of 5000ms
  Stack Trace:
  Failed SingleFail [28 ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 1
  But was:  2

  Stack Trace:
     at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.VVV.VVVSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\VVV\VVVSerializationTest.cs:line 39

1)    at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.VVV.VVVSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\VVV\VVVSerializationTest.cs:line 39


  Failed SingleFail [< 1 ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 1
  But was:  2

  Stack Trace:
     at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.VVV.WWW.WWWSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\VVV\WWW\WWWSerializationTest.cs:line 30

1)    at Net80WindowsTest.AAA.VVV.WWW.WWWSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\AAA\VVV\WWW\WWWSerializationTest.cs:line 30



Failed!  - Failed:     3, Passed:     4, Skipped:     0, Total:     7, Duration: 5 s - Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Net80WindowsTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test matches the given testcase filter `TestCategory!=MemoryTest&TestCategory!=ApartmentSTA&FullyQualifiedName~Net80WindowsTest.BBB` in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll

  Failed SingleFail [17 ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 1
  But was:  2

  Stack Trace:
     at Net80WindowsTest.BBB.BBBSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\BBB\BBBSerializationTest.cs:line 29

1)    at Net80WindowsTest.BBB.BBBSerializationTest.SingleFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\BBB\BBBSerializationTest.cs:line 29



Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     2, Skipped:     0, Total:     3, Duration: 20 ms - Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\bin\Debug\net8.0\TestLibNet80.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Test run for E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\Net80WindowsTest\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Net80WindowsTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

Starting test execution, please wait...
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    18, Skipped:     0, Total:    18, Duration: 99 ms - Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
  Failed AATest [47 ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 2
  But was:  1

  Stack Trace:
     at TestLibNet80.Net80TestClasses.AATest() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\Net80TestClasses.cs:line 16

1)    at TestLibNet80.Net80TestClasses.AATest() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\Net80TestClasses.cs:line 16


  Failed BBRunMe [5 s]
  Error Message:
   Test exceeded Timeout value of 5000ms
  Stack Trace:
  Failed TestFail [2 ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: 2
  But was:  1

  Stack Trace:
     at TestLibNet80.Net80TestClasses.TestFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\Net80TestClasses.cs:line 62

1)    at TestLibNet80.Net80TestClasses.TestFail() in E:\SampleOfReproductions\.Net Plain\Net48NetStandard20\TestLibNet80\Net80TestClasses.cs:line 62


  Failed TimeOutIssueFail [1 s]
  Error Message:
   Test exceeded Timeout value of 1000ms
  Stack Trace:
  Failed ZZHehe [5 s]
  Error Message:
   Test exceeded Timeout value of 5000ms
  Stack Trace:

Failed!  - Failed:     5, Passed:     3, Skipped:     0, Total:     8, Duration: 11 s - TestLibNet80.dll (net8.0)




Note that there are a lot of irrelevant outputs such as :

VSTest version 17.11.0 (x64)

Or

Starting test execution, please wait...

Or

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

So how can I suppress the above redundant messages while still retain the information about the failed tests, and also the stats (eg: Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     4, Skipped:     0, Total:     5, Duration: 16 s - Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)?
I've tried to use --verbosity minimal and --verbosity quiet, both don't do the job.
I'm using NUnit.

I don't think there's really a way to do this without parsing the response, I looked it up and saw the flag --trace=Error (docs), but I don't know if that'll answer your question

maybe writing custom tool to capture output and override it? like in https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

You can use PowerShell and regular expressions to find the strings you want, load the results into variables and format the output.
The following PowerShell script will parse the console output given in the question, store the results and print them into an array. I've stored the console output in a file, but there are many ways to redirect the command's output to a file, or directly to a string. Then, it can be processed with regular expressions.
$output = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt

$output -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match "(\w+)![ -]+Failed:[ ]+(\w+),[ ]+Passed:[ ]+(\w+),[ ]+Skipped:[ ]+(\w+),[ ]+Total:[ ]+(\w+),[ ]+Duration:[ ]+([\w ms]+) - ([\w. ()]+)") {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Result = $Matches[1]
            Failed = $Matches[2]
            Passed = $Matches[3]
            Skipped = $Matches[4]
            Total = $Matches[5]
            Duration = $Matches[6]
            Binary = $Matches[7]
        }
    }
} | Format-Table

This will print the parsed console output as a neat table:
Result Failed Passed Skipped Total Duration Binary                       
------ ------ ------ ------- ----- -------- ------                       
Passed 0      1      0       1     5 ms     TestLibNet80.dll (net8.0)    
Failed 1      4      0       5     16 s     Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Failed 3      4      0       7     5 s      Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Failed 1      2      0       3     20 ms    Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Passed 0      18     0       18    99 ms    Net80WindowsTest.dll (net8.0)
Failed 5      3      0       8     11 s     TestLibNet80.dll (net8.0)    

Here's a visual output of the regular expression that captures the needed strings.

how about using some library like AsciiFormatting

Why would you want to use a C# library in this case? You'd have to create a .NET project to use it, which would be overkill just to parse output from a console command
